# How do I redirect to a studio flow from inside a Twilio Function?

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-studio

I have a serverless function that is executed when an user sends a message through whatsapp, if the user sends a fixed location, the function get it's latitude and longitude and returns an object on the callback with the location info. I want to make the function run and redirect to a studio flow that is integrated with flex through proxy so I can handle the user's location there and eventually send to a flex agent.

This is the function I have:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  console.log("lat: ", event.Latitude);
  console.log("lon: ", event.Longitude);

  if (!event.Latitude || !event.Longitude) {
    callback(null, {
      lat: null,
      lon: null
    });
  } else {
    const location = {
      lat: event.Latitude,
      lon: event.Longitude
    };
    
    callback(null, location);
  }
};
```

I'm using WhatsApp Sandbox with the above function being called on "when a message comes in". After the function executes I want it to redirect to a Studio Flow (inside the function), is that possible? How can I do it? I'm a beginner dev and new to Twilio.

Answer (score 0):

It's technically not a redirect but it is possible to initiate a Studio flow from a function. In this case you need to pass the number of the original sender to the Studio flow  via the following code snippet:

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  client.studio.v2.flows('<Flow ID>')
    .executions
    .create({ to: event.From, from: MY_NUMBER })
    .then(execution => {
      return callback(null, "hello"); // You could return something else as well
    }
};
```

And you can find the ID of your flow in the console (or when you click on the root element and check the `Flow Configuration`):
[image]